# Does tensor product of associative algebras commute with finite products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose A, B, and C are associative rings with unit and $k$ a commutative ring with unit. Is it true that there is a  **ring isomorphism** (not module) $$A\otimes_k(B\times C)\cong (A\otimes_k B)\times (A\otimes_k C)?$$ If $A, B, C$ are commutative this is true, but does it hold in the noncommutative case?

Comment: Do you know what the ring structures are like on both sides? Do you know what the isomorphism should look like (say on simple tensors)?

Comment: The ones induced by the direct product of rings and tensor product of algebras.